# Cannot find module './index.ts' ts-node when launching two scripts simultaniously

Tags: node.js, shell, ubuntu, cron, ts-node

I have two scripts that I both launch on my VPS with a .sh script that runs ts-node if the js script is not running:

```
#!/bin/sh
PROCESS_NAME_REGEX="process_name"
TS_NODE_EXECUTABLE="./node_modules/.bin/ts-node"

if ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -qE "$PROCESS_NAME_REGEX" ; then
        exit 0
else
        $TS_NODE_EXECUTABLE /path/src/index.ts >> ./parser.log &
        exit 0
fi
```

process_name and /path/ are valid, I double checked. Both script launch fine if this is just one script, but when attempted to launch one script while other is running I get error.

```
auto$ cd /path/ && ./always_run.sh
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './index.ts'
Require stack:
- /path/src/imaginaryUncacheableRequireResolveScript
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:127:19)
    at requireResolveNonCached (/var/path/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:549:16)
    at getProjectSearchDir (/var/path/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:519:40)
    at phase3 (/var/www/auto/data/path/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:267:27)
    at bootstrap (/var/path/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:47:30)
    at main (/var/www/auto/data/path/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:33:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/path/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:579:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/path/src/imaginaryUncacheableRequireResolveScript'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.17.1
```

I'm not really experienced in Linux and I guess this might be some env issue or something. Please tell me if I need to provide additional info.